# Get the count for Age >= 50 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset

```
{"data":
"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88"}
```

Need to get the count of age where age is >= 50 using Pandas. I am facing the problem while creating data frame on the above data. Can anyone please help me to figure out the issue ?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

d = {"data": "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64"}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question is unclear: "I am facing the problem while creating data frame on the above data" What is the problem you are having specifically? What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? A [mcve] showing your current output vs your expected output would help us know how to help you better

Comment: try: `
d = [{"key:"IAfpK", "age":58},{"key":"WNVdi","age":64}]`

Comment: Why do you have all the attributes in a single string? You should create a dataframe where each attribute is a separate column.

Comment: It's hard to suggest anything without knowing your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to process your data before pass it to a pandas dataframe. So you can organize your data as recommended in the comments above, or if string is really huge, you can do this:

```py
d = {"data": "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88"}


cleaned = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(','), d['data'].split()))
df=pd.DataFrame(zip(filter(lambda x: 'key' in x, cleaned), 
                    filter(lambda x: 'age' in x, cleaned)), 
                columns=['key','age'])
for i in df:
    df[i]=df[i].str.replace('[\w]+=','',regex=True)
    
df[df['age'].astype(int) >= 50]

>>
     key age
0  IAfpK  58
1  WNVdi  64
3  0Sr4C  68
4  CGEqo  76
5  IxKVQ  79
8  k1SN5  88
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. Its working as expected